# facebook sdk 3.11 post photo to wall

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
Error: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x9d2500 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=500, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 2;
        message = "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 500;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x8ba2d0, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x8c8520, appID: 404542866352356, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x9ba130>, expirationDate: 2014-06-15 12:00:17 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-04-16 12:10:26 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
"create_note",
"basic_info",
"share_item",
"status_update",
"user_friends",
"publish_actions",
"publish_checkins",
"video_upload",
"publish_stream",
"photo_upload",
installed,
"public_profile"
)>
```

have some idea ? I set permissions but nothing changes

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"create_note",
                                @"basic_info",
                                @"share_item",
                                @"status_update",
                                @"user_friends",
                                @"publish_actions",
                                @"publish_checkins",
                                @"video_upload",
                                @"publish_stream",
                                @"photo_upload",
                                @"public_profile",
                                nil];
```